Google Analytics GA4 accounts access from a web application service account
I have a PHP web app that creates Google Analytics GA4 reports.
The app is not retrieving all google GA4 accounts that are listed into analytics dashboard.
I am using Google Analytics Admin for PHP library from here: https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-admin
and Google Analytics Data for PHP library from here:  https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data.
I created an app inside google cloud console, a service account and a private key for it. I downloaded and saved JSON credentials in a local file. I followed these steps: https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#service-account
I am trying to list all available accounts by using analytics admin API and get their properties
I am using some code similar to this:
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Admin\V1beta\AnalyticsAdminServiceClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;

// Authenticating with a keyfile path.
$adminClient = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient([
    'credentials' => '/path/to/credential-file.json'
]);
$dataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient(
    'credentials' => '/path/to/credential-file.json'
]);

$optionalArgs = [ 'pageSize' => 200, 'showDeleted' => true ];
$accounts = $adminClient->listAccounts( $optionalArgs );

$optionalArgs = [ 'pageSize' => 200 ];
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    print 'Found account: ' . $account->getName() . PHP_EOL;
    $properties = $adminClient->listProperties( 'ancestor:' . $account->getName(), $optionalArgs );

    foreach ($properties as $property) {
    print 'Found property: ' . $property->getName() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// ... following code to retrieve properties metrics data etc ...

Code is working fine (I tried to simplify the listing here) but I have an issue:
Not all accounts from analytics dashboard (and their properties) are listed by the app. Only the accounts that have explicit set the app service account as a user. This can be done manually following these staps: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9305788#Add&zippy=%2Cin-this-article
My question is: Is there a way to grant access to an app service account to all analytics accounts without the necessity to make some manually access settings into analytics dashboard for each account one by one? Because I have lots of analytics accounts and from time to time new accounts are added. Or maybe make these access settings only once for all analytics accounts and not for each one separately?
